# how to use distinct only for some items in select query in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query like this

```
select F.F_Stand,    
       T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
       f.F_Localcontact,
       F.F_status
from T_Exhibitor_followup F
left join T_Exhibiton
    on T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Code = F.F_Exhibitor_Code 
where F_Exhibition_Code='12511' and
      F_Area='DWTC' and
      F_Building='SAEED' and
      F_catcode='FN'
```

my out put like this :

```
 Stand no     Name                  number  status
Saeed E136  A. Proctor Group Ltd    123     Pending
Saeed E136  A. Proctor Group Ltd    123     Pending
Saeed E136  A. Proctor Group Ltd    123     Pending
Saeed E136  A. Proctor Group Ltd    123     Delivered
```

I want to get only 1 row out put,if status all Delivered then i want show status 'Deliverd' if any one of status 'Pending' then i want to show status 'Pending'
so i added query like this :in this query i added distinct keyword

```
select  distinct  F.F_Stand, T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,f.F_Localcontact,F.F_status
from T_Exhibitor_followup F left join T_Exhibitor on T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Code=F.F_Exhibitor_Code 
where F_Exhibition_Code='12511' and F_Area='DWTC' and F_Building='SAEED' and F_catcode='FN'
```

but now i am getting out put like this :

```
Saeed E136  A. Proctor Group Ltd    123 Delivered
Saeed E136  A. Proctor Group Ltd    123 Pending
```

still not getting

Comment: But what is your actual desired output?

Comment: write the two queries you want, one with DISTINCT and the other without DISTINCT, make them return the same columns - splice them together with UNION ALL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an aggregation query.  You can do something like this:

```
SELECT F.F_Stand,
       e.F_Exhibitor_Name,
       f.F_Localcontact,
       CASE WHEN MIN(F.F_status) = MAX(f.F_status)
            THEN MIN(F.F_status)
            WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN F.F_status = 'Pending' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            THEN 'Pending'
            ELSE '???'
       END
FROM T_Exhibitor_followup F
LEFT JOIN T_Exhibitor e
    ON e.F_Exhibitor_Code = F.F_Exhibitor_Code 
WHERE F_Exhibition_Code = '12511' AND
      F_Area = 'DWTC' AND
      F_Building = 'SAEED' AND
      F_catcode = 'FN'
GROUP BY F.F_Stand,
         e.F_Exhibitor_Name,
         f.F_Localcontact;
```

The logic for the `case` is:

- If all statuses are the same, then use that status.
- If any status is pending then call it `'Pending'`.
- Otherwise, output `'???'`.

Comment: so fast it's scary...it helps to not be on a cell phone

Comment: HAHAHA Agreed @TimBiegeleisen I think Gordon get's question alerts like 3 minutes ahead of everyone else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` in order to prioritize `'Pending'` over `'Delivered'` status:

```
select F.F_Stand,    
       T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
       f.F_Localcontact,
       F.F_status
from (
   select F.F_Stand,    
          T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Name,
          f.F_Localcontact,
          F.F_status,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                         WHEN F.F_status = 'Pending' THEN 0 
                                         ELSE 1
                                      END) AS rn
   from T_Exhibitor_followup F
   left join T_Exhibiton
       on T_Exhibitor.F_Exhibitor_Code = F.F_Exhibitor_Code 
  where F_Exhibition_Code='12511' and
         F_Area='DWTC' and
         F_Building='SAEED' and
         F_catcode='FN') as t
where t.rn =1
```

The above query works provided that there are only `two` possible values for `status` field:

- `'Pending'` and
- `'Delivered'`

You can add an extra field in the `ORDER` clause of the window function in order to prioritize records having the same `status` value.